# How can I make the prediction run automatically?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tf.keras, predict

I am making my first neural network using Keras libraries in Google Colab.

Once the network is trained, I make predictions like this:

```
# image path
img_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/manchas-negras-tomate-alternaria.jpg'

# load a single image
new_image = load_image(img_path)

# check prediction
pred = modelo_rrnn_tomate.predict(new_image)
print(pred)
np.argmax(pred)
```

and execute this function to make my prediction.

My question is the following, how can I make the prediction run automatically.

That is, for my application I would be interested in if there is a photo in X folder, it executes the prediction, sends me the result class and I delete the folder, and that it works like this automatically.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible to automate the process of making predictions on images in a folder and then deleting the folder once the predictions are made. You can achieve this using Python's file handling capabilities along with the functionalities provided by Keras and Google Colab.